# How do I find the green function for this ODE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I apologize in advance that I don't know lexicon. I would appreciate it if someone can edit it. This is the problem:

$$\frac{d^2u}{dx^2}+u=f(x), \quad 0 < x<1$$

$$u'(0)=A$$
$$u(1)=B$$

Here is my work:

$$\frac{d^2G}{dx^2}+G=\delta(x-x_0)$$

$$ G(x) = \left\{ \begin{matrix} a\sin x+b\cos x, & x < x_0 \\ 
c\sin(x-1)+d\cos(x-1), & x > x_0 \end{matrix} \right.$$

I apply boundary conditions and get this

$$ G(x) = \left\{ \begin{matrix} A\sin x+b\cos x, & x < x_0 \\ 
c\sin(x-1)+B\cos(x-1), & x > x_0 \end{matrix} \right.$$

I'm not sure how to find the other coefficients, b and c. In other problems with homogenous boundary conditions, two coefficients constant would equal zero after applying the boundary conditions, but it doesn't work in this case. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

There are two more conditions:

1) $G$ is continuous at $x=x_0$, and

2) $$\lim_{\epsilon \to 0}\left ( \left [\frac{d}{dx} G(x,x_0) \right ]_{x=x_0+\epsilon} - \left [\frac{d}{dx} G(x,x_0) \right ]_{x=x_0-\epsilon} \right ) = 1$$

Use the forms you derived using the boundary conditions on either side of $x=x_0$ to find the other unknown coefficients.